How do I start a search with the currently selected text?
What to add to init.lua such that / set the CLI with:

/ followed by the selected text if any
/ otherwise


I took the freedom to reformulate your question. Feel free to discard my edition if I have misunderstood your demand :-)

I would do in Lua:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("v", "/", '"vy/<C-r>v', { noremap=true})

Or its equivalent in Vimscript (for init.vim):
vnoremap / "vy/<C-r>v

With this in Visual mode:

"vy yank the selection in the v register
/ tiggers the search
<C-r>v paste the content of the v register into the command line

Plugin Suggestion:
You could be interested by the vim-visual-star-search plugin that extend the * search to the selected text.
In Vim if you hit * in Normal mode Vim searches for the next occurrence of the current word. With vim-visual-star-search if you hit * in Visual mode Vim searches for the next occurrence of the selected text.
